# I can be heavy, but I'll never sink. When I am ready, my glass is a drink

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riley Riddle:**
>
> *My prefix runs past, 
>  When you leave what you cast, 
>  Where a square may be skipped by a pawn.* 
>  
>  *My suffix is vast, 
>  When I swap first with last, 
>  Where a breath may be currently drawn.* 
>  
>  *My infix is fast, 
>  When it thinks in a blast, 
>  Where a net may be used thereupon.* 
>  
>  *I am certainly classed, 
>  As a type of forecast, 
>  With a rumble in shields and my spawn.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

I don't mean to boast, but I found this riddle so *romantic*, I even *cried*.

---

**Not part of the riddle:**

Apparently my title appears to be subjective and so this question is likely to be closed. If you agree, I will change the title. This will also be my final riddle for a couple of days because I need to focus on my school musical and tests.
$$$$
**Edit:**

@[PerpetualJ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51105/perpetualj) was awarded a $+50$ reputation bounty. 
 @[NicolásMango](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52027/nicol%C3%A1s-magno) was awarded a $+100$ reputation bounty.

---

**Hint 1:**

> *I might wear a bow, 
>  Where in grey it will glow, 
>  When I fall from the head to the toe. 
>  
>  My coat is yellow, 
>  Where the classic shall know, 
>  When the keeper feels splashes below.*

**Bonus if (and only if!) you read Hint 1:**

> *Two colours are heard, 
>  Though my bow has a third, 
>  So as to what name shall this be referred? 
>  
>  There are seven to choose, 
>  Mainly caught in the blues, 
>  So reflect, what indicated the shoes?*

**Hint 2:**

> <sup>Written from my own perspective; the following inclusive language refers not to the answer, but to me, @MrPie.</sup> 
>  *Riddle me this: 
>  Alone and in bliss, 
>  I cast myself,
>  Not unlike yourself. 
>  
>  A short soldier walks. 
>  When in front, it blocks. 
>  But it starts to run, 
>  When it skips just one. 
>  
>  Desiring a breath, 
>  I will live until death, 
>  But a breath of what? 
>  It is felt but not sought. 
>  
>  A net meets the eye, 
>  On light like the sky, 
>  But it might not be mine. 
>  How might you define?*

**Suffix Hint (<sub><sup>@[PerpetualJ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51105/perpetualj) requested a hint on the suffix, and perhaps like-minded users would want one, too</sup></sub>):**

> *You feel the suffix on your flesh, 
>  When outside, smelly or fresh. 
>  It might be warm or rather cool; 
>  Although not a liquid, it is a fuel.*

**Shoes Hint (<sub><sup>this is the only part that requires knowledge, for which I felt the need to write this after looking at @[Elpharya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51806/elpharya)'s answer</sup></sub>):**

> *The shoes are not ruby nor magic, 
>  Where clicking them thrice is but tragic. 
>  Explore below, not somewhere over, 
>  Where the keeper does not hold a clover.*

Comment: Beauty this is, King Riley is proud; such a fine riddle, it shines through the clouds. +1

Comment: @user477343 Yep nice riddle, don't change the title mate. Btw, good luck on ur tests :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ thank you! I also like the rhyme :D

Comment: Now that's a damn good poem. Did you write this yourself?

Comment: @Cubemaster thank you! And yes, I did :D

Comment: Any relation to Iceberg? Glacier?

Comment: @Moti nope. Some words in the title are written with an intention to make you think certain things, when actually that is not the answer; but glacier is a good suggestion, because it sounds like "glass" :D

Comment: Just noticed that your acrostic nature for this is ***MWW***. That's awesome that almost your entire puzzle was able to stick to this theme of ***My, When, Where***!

Comment: "Thinking in a blast" - I can't help but think of Jimmy Neutron... Gotta blast!

Comment: @PerpetualJ thank you! I might be doing this theme again since it seems a lot of people like it :D

Comment: @Elpharya hahah, it’s not jimmy neutron. In fact, that is probably the only line not to be taken literally... otherwise you’d be thinking **for too long** :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **Feedback to the Poster**

I really enjoyed this puzzle, and have enjoyed looking for the answers. The finesse of your rhyming was quite impeccable! You definitely have my up-vote here! You should consider submitting this to a puzzle challenge similar to the local newspaper where I live. They hold weekly challenges allowing the community to compete for a spot in the paper! You'd definitely win with this one!

### **My Answer**

> Rain

I wasn't able to find a 100% representation for it without going into a unique perspective. I really look forward to the poster's **Making Of** answer.

---

**Prefix**: This is a tough one, but it fits perfectly.

> **Ran** is past, without what you cast; a pawn skips one when it starts.
>  
>  
>  ***My prefix runs past***: And I ran, I ran so far away. 10 points if you name the song.
>  
>  ***When you leave what you cast***: Remove the letter I.
>  
>  ***Where a square may be skipped by a pawn***: This is a reference to how a pawn can move either one or two squares forward for it's opening movement. This can also be a reference to En Passant which literally translates to *in passing*, alternatively *run past*; this is a move in which a pawn can capture another pawn under specific criteria; see my interesting finds section.

---

**Infix**: Quite simple unless you're overthinking it like most of us initially did.

> **AI** is fast, in processing a blast; and casts a net from its heart.
>  
>  
>  ***My infix is fast***: AI operates quickly.
>  
>  ***When it thinks in a blast**: AI thinks the same way humans do by creating *blasts* in their “brains” like neurons firing off.
>  
>  ***Where a net may be used thereupon***: Heuristic algorithms (heavily used in AI development) are analogous to nets as they try many different paths, finding the path of least resistance with the most accuracy and learning along the way. Although, another analogy can be made here to the internet as a whole, which can be used to run AI; although I don't believe in the cloud, it's just someone else's computer. :)

---

**Suffix**: The middle line to this stanza throws everyone off, but it was probably phrased that way for rhyming's sake.

> **Air** is vast, is quite a gas; this riddle is ingeniously smart.
>  
>  
>  ***My suffix is vast***: Air is everywhere and as such is quite vast.
>  
>  ***When I swap first with last***: More than first and last, but none the less.
>  
>  ***Where a breath may be currently drawn***: You breathe air.
>  
>  
>  I think I would have rephrased this a little to be more accurate; though, it was a great riddle.
>  
>  My suffix is vast,
>  
>  Reordered out last (eventually someone will realize to drop the *n*),
>  
>  Where a breath may be currently drawn.

---

### **The Hints**

**Hint 1**: This definitely fits all criteria in the riddle and retains the same prefix.

> Yellow in color; but known as another; a **raincoat** this seems to be.

**Hint 2**: This was a dead giveaway!

> **Rain** you seek, it took not a week; but an acrostic gave this to me.

**Suffix Hint**: This took a while to solve when coupled with the riddle.

> **Air** is warm, and rather cool; a fuel for life unseen.
>  
>  
>  Air is the basis of all life; well, oxygen is anyways. The air you breathe is indeed a fuel for your body to keep going, without it, you will die. The hard part in finding this was swapping first with last. You actually have to remove the last letter, and reorder what's left.

**Shoes Hint**: It would seem that most are referring to Dorothy and her ruby red slippers (not shoes). I believe this is referring to:

> **Rainboots** below, in rain and snow; keep your feet dry all the same.
>  
>  
>  I believe this is in reference to hint 1 and the bonus. Granted, I don't think it has anything to do with the color references, just ***When the keeper feels splashes below*** and ***So reflect, what indicated the shoes?***.

**Bonus**: Again meets all the criteria (same prefix as well).

> Silver and gold, as time has foretold; a **rainbow** the future will bring.
>  
>  **Indigo** the color, unlike no other; found through blues in-between.
>  
>  
>  This is in reference to indigo being a shade of blue between the other two blue hues (blue and violet). The colors of the rainbow are red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo and violet. I actually forgot the exact colors involved and had to look it up.

### ***Interesting Finds***

I have found a few cool things while searching for the answer. I figure I'll share these with the community in the hopes that you all enjoy them too!

> - [Thundersnow](http://weather.wikia.com/wiki/Thundersnow) - It rarely occurs, but it is a snow storm accompanied by thunder and lightning.
> - [Squall Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squall_line) - A narrow band of high winds and storms associated with a cold front. We see these a lot where I live!
> - The acrostic for each stanza seems to follow the pattern of ***MWW***; this was interesting and beautifully crafted! I love the flow of the ***My, When, Where*** pattern. The puzzle as a whole (including hints and bonus) only deviates from this occasionally.
> - [Dark ’N’ Stormy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_%27n%27_Stormy) - This is a type of alcoholic drink, definitely did not know this; I'm more of *old fashioned, on the rocks*.
> - [En Passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) **(Credit to Cubemaster)** - En Passant (in passing, run past, or by the way) is a movement in which a pawn can capture a pawn abreast itself that made a opening two step movement. This is the case when a pawn at D7 moves to D5, an enemy pawn on E5 can capture by moving to D6.
> - [Pawn Promotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(chess)) - Pawn promotion allows a pawn to technically skip squares once promoted to a rook, knight, bishop, or queen. This is more of lateral thinking.
> - [Opening Movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_(chess)#Movement) - There is a special movement for pawns where they can move two squares instead of one, so long as it is their first movement.

Comment: Oooo... close! You are on the right track :D

Comment: Pawn promotion allows a *pawn* to technically skip squares once promoted to a rook, knight, bishop, or queen. This is more of lateral thinking. In regards to the opening two-step, there isn't really a name for it since it is just a basic movement.

Comment: Congratulations! $\boxed{\color{blue}{+50}}$

Comment: @NicolásMango, I challenge you to read the comments above for the final hint (the *final* final). But it is likely that you may not be getting a tick, and perhaps a $100$ rep bounty. This should match up reputation points and be appropriate, too, because don't you agree that **PerpetualJ**'s answer was created via *heaps* of effort?

Comment: @user477343 Let's clean up the comments on this post. I'll note all as many as possible in my answer prior to deletion, this way the post can reflect everything in the comments, and the page can remain clean.

Comment: @NicolásMagno Please see my above comment. Do you mind assisting with this by removing your comment(s) as well?

Comment: @Cubemaster Please see my above comment. Do you mind assisting with this by removing your comment(s) as well?

Comment: @NicolásMagno Everybody casts themselves; we cause light to shine on ourselves (cast) everyday so we can see! Therefore, **I** cast myself. If you read the sentence in first person, you would not read, "When you leave what you cast" but instead would read, "When **I** leave what I cast". This means to leave out the **I** in **RAIN**, thus getting **RAN**. I have deleted my other comment explaining this; agreeing with **PerpetualJ**, I will try to clear these comments :P

Comment: @PerpetualJ will do, but am keeping the "Congratulations $\boxed{\color{blue}{+50}}$" comment :P

Comment: @user477343 Also, please give my answer another once over to see my changes; you could also view them in the edit pane so that you can find the changes faster since it's such a large post. I will remove this comment tomorrow afternoon, and I look forward to your making of answer!

Comment: Well, it is all correct! The net part especially (*internet* was a great attempt and could have also passed, but your explanation regarding that part was what I was thinking of). Caught in the blues can also refer to rain, but sometimes rainbows can shine *after* it rains, so I prefer your explanation to that as well. It's all amazing, and well deserving of the tick! :D

Answer (score 6):

**Prefix**

```
My prefix runs past, 
When you leave what you cast, 
Where a square may be skipped by a pawn.
```

> **RAN**. Based on @PerpetualJ answer: It makes sense, since the pawn "runs" when it moves two squares and it is the past tense of run.

**Infix**

```
My infix is fast, 
When it thinks in a blast, 
Where a net may be used thereupon.
```

> **AI**. An **A**rtificial **I**ntelligence is usually fast and a net (Internet) may be used to improve it or to run it.

**Suffix**

```
My suffix is vast, 
When I swap first with last,
Where a breath may be currently drawn.
```

-Hint

```
You feel the suffix on your flesh, 
When outside, smelly or fresh. 
It might be warm or rather cool; 
Although not a liquid, it is a fuel.
```

> **AIR**. Air is one of our "fuels", which we breath. It can be smelly, fresh, warm and/or cool.

Answer

> We have **RAN**, **AI** and **AIR**. All of which forms **Rain** when arranged with a certain pattern I have not deciphered yet. Rain has bows (rainbows), has coats (raincoats) and is a type of forecast. It can be heavy and, when ready (when it "becomes water", as it's no longer rain), it is now a glass of water or a drink. As @user477343 said: RAIN is not the prefix. But it actually is the answer.

**Bonus**

> **Indigo**. One uses shoes to go somewhere, so the shoes **indi**cated to **go**. It's also a color in the blue spectrum, between violet and blue in a rainbow.

---

MISC

> The answer is actually the initials of the first paragraph of Hint 2. Clever :)

---

Comment: That's it! You got it! Someone finally got it! Woo! :D .... Except the prefix, but since you answered everything else correct, I will suggest reading Hint $2$, particularly the first paragraph... (I also have to wait just $2$ more hours before I can upvote again).

Comment: Now, if you will, are you going to try and answer the bonus? :P **Edit:** Also, adding to my previous comment, Rot13(enva pna ybbx tynffl), and after reading the bio in your profile, I must say, I am quite glad you joined the **Puzzling Stack Exchange**! :D

Comment: Thank you. I'm really enjoying it! Let me tell you, your puzzles are quite engulfing! **Edit**: I also added to the answer based on your hint

Comment: I do really try to make my puzzles a bit more puzzly than your "average puzzle", so thank you! That means a lot to me :P ... There is also a little bit more to Hint 2 that will particularly help you with the prefix, though, if you want to fully solve it. But either way, you will be getting the tick, and I will be posting a "Making Of" answer. It won't be an actual answer, but just an answer to show how I made the puzzle :D

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in really tough puzzles, I recommend you check out @[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)'s profile and take a look at some of his/her puzzles. Beware, though, they are quite tough :P

Comment: It's tough man. I'm still thinking about the prefix. The only thing I could find is "alone and in bliss", rot13( oyvff nf unccvarff naq A vf nybar ). But so are others...

Comment: You are right: so is another letter. In fact, Rot13(fb vf nabgure yrggre va "oyvff")....

Comment: rot13( VA. V naq A ner nybar va unccvarff. V vf nyfb hfrq gb ersre gb barfrys ("V pnfg zlfrys"). Gur cersvk vf VA! )

Comment: Ooohhh... that's not it. Rot13(Lbh bayl unir gb hfr gur jbeq "oyvff", naq ab bgure jbeq; gubhtu vs lbh pna svaq na nygreangvir nafjre ertneqvat gur jbeq "unccvarff" gura tb sbe vg, ohg guhf sne, lbh unira'g dhvgr)... it is simpler than you think :)

Comment: Didn’t I respond with this at some point? 11th revision was rain, though I couldn’t fully explain it.

Comment: @PerpetualJ yeah you did, but I thought you insisted the *answer* wasn't actually that, but it had something do with it, instead :\

Comment: No, revision 11 states the answer as rain but that I wasn’t fully able to explain how lol

Comment: I can update my answer back to that if you’d like.

Comment: I just realized about the Bonus. I thought you were talking about the prefix, but it isn't just that. What are you referring to as "the Bonus"?

Comment: @NicolásMagno the bonus is referring to the third colour. What is it? :P

Comment: @PerpetualJ if you want to update your answer, sure! But if so, it might just be a battle between you and this answer for who gets all the explanations correct, first. Now I know it is a jumbo of a riddle that requires a lot of explaining, so I guess if you are answering the bonus, it is optional to include the explanation for all the hints below it. I will provide a full and thorough explanation of the entire riddle in a wrap-up "making of" answer once i have accepted (and possibly awarded the 100 rep bounty) :D

Comment: I just made an attempt at the color. Is it that one?

Comment: @NicolásMagno it is sooooooo close, Blues does not refer to that. In fact, the answer is in your explanation for the bonus! (Also, the shoes is not that, either... but given the Shoes Hint, your answer does make nearly perfect sense; the last line of that hint ruins your answer)

Comment: Yeah, you got it, now... now you just need to find some explanation as to how it **indi**cates the shoes... or not. I mean, you have the answer now, and I will be posting a full-explanation answer, anyways. It's up to you; I'm going to bed :D

Comment: Updated the answer. Still some things missing, like the pattern to arrange the letters.

Comment: It's all good. This is good enough. $\boxed{\color{blue}{+100}}$ :D

Answer (score 3):

-*Partial answer*-

Is the prefix

> Rain?

Since

> Rain is a kind of forecast, there are rainbows, and raincoats are yellow.

I can't seem to figure out the rest of it :/

Comment: How does this fit the prefix/suffix/infix parts?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE; please elaborate as to how you arrived at your answer by explaining how it relates to the puzzle. This will help us better understand your answer.

Comment: Well... you are not wrong, but where is the explanation? :D

Comment: Wait what do you mean it isn't wrong. Surely the answer isn't just "rain"?

Comment: I think on a technicality **rain** in itself is heavily involved in the desired answer. Meaning we're definitely looking for a low pressure style system. I believe @user477343 may just want Stefan to elaborate on the provided answer.

Comment: @Cubemaster well... you might be surprised at what the answer is. I mean, the wording is all supposed to sound confusing... but the answer is nice and simple :D

Comment: @PerpetualJ yes I do want that. Whether he has it correct or not, I would want that from every answer :)

Comment: Right, I only mentioned the prefix, sorry guys it's my first time posting here and I didn't notice the prefix/infix/suffix part.

Comment: @Stefan no worries, that's ok. The word "rain" is not the prefix... but is very close to it..... *very* close.

Answer (score 3):

Is this

> Entrainment? [Wikipedia describes this an atmoshperic phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrainment_(meteorology))

Prefix

> I believe the move to skip a pawn is called En Passant, so EN

Infix

> Trains can be pretty fast, and they burn a fuel source to move

Suffix

> Not one hundred percent on this part

I'm pretty sure I'm not at the right answer, but figured it was worth a shot

Answer (score 3):

A try at the bonus:

Two colours are heard

> which is Blue (below) and Yellow (Hint 1)

Though my bow has a third,
So as to what name shall this be referred?

There are seven to choose,
Mainly caught in the blues,
So reflect, what indicated the shoes?

> I think the colour of the bow is RED. The shoes in the last line refer to Dorothy's red shoes (from Wizard of Oz), and in the film she also sings "Over the Rainbow", which seems a fitting topic.
>  Another note is that with red, it seems all three colours are primary

Comment: WOW! That is not the answer, but Jesus, that.... that's, like, another answer! That's amazing. $(+1)$ I wish I could spend more than one upvote on this!! You got both the colours correct (with wrong reasoning, but still very very good)! You didn't get mixed up with shade.... (if you know what I mean...). Think about the splashes below...

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I'll try to keep thinking of an answer for this tricky riddle :)

Comment: I tried making people think the other colour was Rot13(terl), but I am glad most who have answered thus far have not actually said that which is good :)

Comment: Missed a color by the way, grey is in the first hint.

Comment: I totally forgot about grey tbh, but blue and yellow fit for my answer so I went with that hah

Comment: @PerpetualJ well technically grey is a **shade**, but is not found on the rainbow anyways (which is why *in* grew, it will glow, if you know what I mean) :)

Answer (score 2):

***Partial Answer***

Just some notes on possible solutions to clues.

> The first stanza sounds like it may be referring to chess towards the end, and there is a move known as "en passant" that allows pawns to do some funky stuff with skipping squares and capturing pawns. Might have something to do with that.

Also, the hints seem to be certainly talking about a

> Rainbow.

Because:

> There are seven to choose,
> Mainly caught in the blues,
> So reflect, what indicated the shoes?
>
> 7 Colors on the spectrum, blue is the wavelength caught by the sky

Next possibility:

> The last stanza of the second hint might be talking about leprechauns and gold. Leprechauns are the "keeper" of the gold, and are a pretty classic creature. So maybe that is what is being referenced?

Based on the Title:

> It might be some sort of cloud. They can weigh millions of pounds, but they stay afloat. Not sure of the latter half of the title, but might refer to rain. Maybe something like "cumulonimbus", as those are storm clouds. Or maybe "Nimbostratus" or "thunderhead"

Comment: Good catch on rot13(ra cnffnag)! It is a rather unusual movement. It does seem to fit the billet; when translated it means rot13(ol gur jnl) and rot13(jnl) could be our prefix, such as rot13(ra) could also. +1

Comment: Well, Maybe we take that and try to apply it to "When you leave what you cast"

Comment: En passant sounds like "run past" (en = run; passant = past), so that is a good theory, but sadly, that has nothing to do with the answer. There is a simpler move in chess that allows the pawn to skip just one square. It makes the pawn move faster than it's usual pace... and pawns aren't the fastest pieces on the board. (That is a hint.) The Rainbow part is definitely correct, but blue does not refer to the wavelength of the sky... that is a different colour, also mentioned in the riddle. (That is another hint.) No leprechaun is being referenced. It's more of a colour that is classic (hint) :D

Comment: The title is definitely referring to both a cloud and the answer itself! But it's not necessarily referring to storm clouds nor thunder, in particular. It is more of the *glassy* look, that counts :)

Comment: Glass Cloud? I didn't know you were into Metalcore Music!

Comment: I am, but I haven't heard of them... oooo you are so close!! It really is quite simple :)))

Comment: In reference to pawns not being the fastest; the rook, bishop, and queen, are the fastest by direction; the knight is the fastest overall as it can jump pieces. Technically a knight is just one of the king's pawns and is often used as such during sacrificial plays.

Comment: The first time a pawn is moved from its starting place it can skip a square... not sure if there's a name for that though

Comment: @Elpharya there is no name for that, but you have to make an analogy. I will add more to the second hint.