# A Striking Resemblance (no.1)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

I was inspired by the `Teapot` riddles and have decided to attempt a new type of `wordplay` puzzle. This should prove to be fun! Good luck to you all!

---

### The Puzzle

> If you look to the west, you're often perplexed, by sights which you cannot explain.
>
> You may try your best, to pass this test, in the end confused you remain.
>
> It looks like a maze, by time it's not fazed, but we all become baffled the same.
>
> I'll sit on my stump, while it beats you up, leaving you flummoxed without a name.

---

What is the word?

Also, since this is the first in the set; explain the title.

Comment: OK, just to see if I'm on the right track: (rot13) Vf gur nafjre eryngrq gb ynathntrf?

Comment: @Racso I'm not sure if I understand your question. Either way that I've interpreted it, the answer is no. It is not related to the tag, nor the difference between one or another.

Comment: The poetry rhythm reminds me of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70978/i-can-be-heavy-but-ill-never-sink-when-i-am-ready-my-glass-is-a-drink). O, the good ol’ days, hahah :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Bamboozled? (Though technically correct, the intended answer is puzzle.)

There are

> A bunch of synonyms in the poem, namely:

If you look to the west, you're often perplexed, by sights which you cannot explain.

> Perplexed, cannot explain

You may try your best, to pass this test, in the end confused you remain.

> Confused

It looks like a maze, by time it's not fazed, but we all become baffled the same.

> Baffled

I'll sit on my stump, while it beats you up, leaving you flummoxed without a name.

> Flummoxed

Comment: I would love to accept this as the answer but there is a particular word that is quite simplistic that fits. I've determined that these aren't the best way to do this kind of puzzle as it is a more of *guess what I'm thinking* type. I think I need to find a better way to do it. Due to this, I'm accepting your answer because it is technically correct; however, I'd love the correct word to be in your answer so I'll edit to show it. +1 From me! Back to the drawing board on how to make this a more narrow search.

Comment: No problem, and again, apologies for not making this a more narrow scope.